# Prevent compose row with two views from squashing a view down to nothing

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to make a composable with two text views that grow in size toward each other. If either view is too big to fit, they should be ellipsized, but I don't want either view to ever be completely invisible.

This *almost* works:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun InfoRow(
    value: String,
    label: String?,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    Row(
        modifier.fillMaxWidth(1f),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        label?.let {
            Text(
                text = it,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                maxLines = 1,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
            )
        }

        Text(
            text = value,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(
                top = 10.dp,
                bottom = 10.dp,
                end = 10.dp
            ),
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.button,
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
            maxLines = 1,
        )
    }
}
```

the problem is when the label is long, it squashes the value down to nothing:

[image: previews]

I haven't been able to get it working by adding `weight` because then it will either squash the label down to nothing or it won't let one of the text views occupy most of the row (like in the 3rd and 4th previews).

For example, adding `weight(1f, false)` to the first `Text` fixes the first preview, but breaks the 2nd and 3rd since now the value squishes the label down to nothing. Adding weight to the second `Text` seems to have no effect.

Comment: Try passing `false` for weight fill. `.weight(1f, false)`

Comment: @TrentMeyer I tried adding that to either/both and it didn't work. One Text always seems to crowd out the other or they aren't allowed to fill the row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `TextMeasurer`.

[image]

**Code**

```
@Composable
fun InfoRow(
    value: String,
    label: String?,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    val textMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()
    BoxWithConstraints {
        val boxWidth = maxWidth
        val valueWidth = textMeasurer.measure(
            value, style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleSmall,
        ).size.width

        var applyWeight = false
        Row(
            modifier.fillMaxWidth(1f),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            label?.let {
                val labelWidth = textMeasurer.measure(
                    label, style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge,
                ).size.width

                val sumWidth = with(LocalDensity) {
                    (labelWidth + valueWidth).pxToDp()
                }

                if (sumWidth > boxWidth) {
                    applyWeight = true
                }
                val weightModifier = if (applyWeight) {
                    Modifier.weight(1F, false)
                } else {
                    Modifier
                }
                Text(
                    text = it,
                    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                    maxLines = 1,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge,
                    modifier = weightModifier
                        .background(Color.Red),
                )
            }

            val weightModifier = if (applyWeight) {
                Modifier.weight(1F, false)
            } else {
                Modifier
            }
            Text(
                text = value,
                modifier = weightModifier
                    .padding(
                        top = 10.dp,
                        bottom = 10.dp,
                        end = 10.dp
                    )
                    .background(Color.Cyan),
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleSmall.copy(
                    textAlign = TextAlign.End,
                ),
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                maxLines = 1,
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**Demo**

```
@Composable
fun MultipleTextDemo() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
    ) {
        InfoRow(
            label = null,
            value = "Short value",
        )
        InfoRow(
            label = null,
            value = "Very long value Very long value Very long value Very long value Very long value Very long value ",
        )
        InfoRow(
            label = "Short Label",
            value = "Short value",
        )
        InfoRow(
            label = "Short Label",
            value = "Very long value Very long value Very long value",
        )
        InfoRow(
            label = "Short Label",
            value = "Very long value Very long value Very long value Very long value Very long value Very long value ",
        )
        InfoRow(
            label = "Very long value Very long value Very ",
            value = "Short value",
        )
        InfoRow(
            label = "Very long value Very long value Very long value Very long value Very long value Very long value ",
            value = "Short value",
        )
        InfoRow(
            label = "Very long value Very long value Very long value Very long value Very long value Very long value ",
            value = "Very long value Very long value Very long value Very long value Very long value Very long value ",
        )
    }
}
```

Make sure to apply correct value and style for text measuring.

Comment: This seems to work! I'll give it a bit more time before I accept in case anyone has a simpler solution.

Comment: Your second-to-last preview is not quite right: there's more room for the label so it shouldn't be limited to half the view. The logic I've settled on is 1) if total width of label + value is not too long, don't set weights, else 2) if label width is more than half the total, set weight on label and, 3) if value width is more than half the total, set weight on value. the key is you need to be able to set weights on neither, both, value, or label. That fixes all cases.